# Sequelize is not associated to

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I don't know what's wrong with my code. I am getting `SequelizeEagerLoadingError` as an error

```js
EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: role is not associated to user!
  at Function._getIncludedAssociation (C:\Users\ik\Documents\getstudy-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:715:13)
  at Function._validateIncludedElement (C:\Users\ik\Documents\getstudy-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:619:53)
  at C:\Users\ik\Documents\getstudy-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:516:37
  at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at Function._validateIncludedElements (C:\Users\ik\Documents\getstudy-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:511:39)
  at C:\Users\ik\Documents\getstudy-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1726:14
  at tryCatcher (C:\Users\ik\Documents\getstudy-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
  at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\ik\Documents\getstudy-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
  at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\ik\Documents\getstudy-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
  at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\ik\Documents\getstudy-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
  at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\ik\Documents\getstudy-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:729:18)
  at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\ik\Documents\getstudy-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:93:12)
  at _drainQueue (C:\Users\ik\Documents\getstudy-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9)
  at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\ik\Documents\getstudy-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5)
  at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\ik\Documents\getstudy-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)      
  at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

I had tried to test the association with this

```js
const test = await user.findOne({ include: [{ model: role }] });
```

models role

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Role = sequelize.define(
    "role",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      description: DataTypes.TEXT,
      active: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      created_at: DataTypes.DATE,
      created_by: DataTypes.JSON,
      updated_at: DataTypes.DATE,
      updated_by: DataTypes.JSON,
      deleted_at: DataTypes.DATE,
      deleted_by: DataTypes.JSON,
    },
    {
      tableName: "role",
      underscored: true,
    }
  );
  Role.associate = function (models) {
    Role.hasMany(models.user);
  };
  return Role;
};
```

models user

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "user",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      role_id: DataTypes.UUID,
      user_id: DataTypes.STRING,
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      password: DataTypes.STRING,
      data_login: DataTypes.JSON,
      profile: DataTypes.JSON,
      verify: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      active: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      created_at: DataTypes.DATE,
      created_by: DataTypes.JSON,
      updated_at: DataTypes.DATE,
      updated_by: DataTypes.JSON,
      deleted_at: DataTypes.DATE,
      deleted_by: DataTypes.JSON,
    },
    {
      tableName: "user",
      underscored: true,
    }
  );
  User.associate = function (models) {
    User.belongsTo(models.role, { foreignKey: "role_id" });
  };
  return User;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.js` file where you initialize your `sequelize` connection, you need to call the associate functions.

```
//index.js
const UserModel = require('./models/user');
const RoleModel = require('./models/role');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME, 
    process.env.DB_USER,
    process.env.DB_PASS, {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT
}); //initialize connection as needed

let models = {}
sequelize.authenticate().then(function(){
  const User = UserModel(sequelize, Sequelize);
  const Role = RoleModel(sequelize, Sequelize);
  User.associate(); //make sure you are calling this
  Role.associate(); 
  models = {User, Role}
})
module.exports = {models, sequelize}
```

The query should run as expected.